# How to auto-fill the row's column based on the row above?

Tags: date, google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have a Google sheet where the 1st row is the date and it will autofill every day. So does the row "Value 1" & "Value 2". Now, I've added manually a row name "SUM" with sum formula.

My question is, how can the row be automated every day so that I do not need to manually drag the formula to the right?

Here's the example sheet:-
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gkKn-tDxosXQGvOdYMj8CupEdG9YXi4sB8PegojDS58/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

paste in **B1** cell:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(TEXT(ROW(INDIRECT("A"&
 DATEVALUE("2019-9-1")&":A"&
 DATEVALUE(TODAY()))), "d/m/yy")))
```

[image: 0]

---

paste in **B4** cell:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MMULT(TRANSPOSE(ROW(
 INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2, 2)&":"&ADDRESS(ROW()-1, MAX(IF(1:1<>"", COLUMN(1:1), ))))))^0, 
 INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2, 2)&":"&ADDRESS(ROW()-1, MAX(IF(1:1<>"", COLUMN(1:1), ))))))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Hmm I really don't understand it. What is the formula that makes it a SUM because I might need to use the formula for MINUS & DIVIDE too? Also, what if the "Value 1" and "Value 2" row is in different row like B2 & B8?

Comment: formula is MMULT because simple SUM will not work in ARRAYFORMULA. MMULT can handle all operators ( + - * / ) - https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/mmult-function-in-google-sheets/ ... https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/array-formula-to-sum-multiple-columns-in-google-sheets/ as for the Values being in B2 and B8 instead of B2 and B3 (like on the picture) - it doesnt matter mmult can handle it. ADDRESS(2,2) means B2 and ADDRESS(ROW()-1, means "whatever row this formula is in minus 1 row" so if you put this formula in B10 it will work with rowas B2:B9